# Magento 2: Export All Products with their custom options

Tags: magento2, custom-options, products, export, database-export

I want to export all products with their custom options through database.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use magento default export functionality

go to **"System -> Data Transfer -> Export"** and select **"Product"**

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did this but all the custom options and their values are coming in a single column. I want them to be in separate columns. Also, I have created additional custom options which are not showing up as well.

Comment: then you have to create custom script or go through 3rd party extension. have a look this if works for you https://www.mlx-store.com/magento2-extensions/export-import/import-export-product-custom-option-for-magento-2.html